# Jquery loop - capture the value

Tags: php, jquery

I am running this loop in php but using a jquery click function during the output.  How can i record which instance of $i was clicked.  When I use $(this) it returns the id.

The $('#pid-form').val('$frame_id[$i]') actually has the number i want as the value but I am not sure how to use it or convert it to a variable that I can use.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numRecords2; $i++){

$prod_id = $_SESSION['prod_array'][$frame_id[$i]];
echo"

$('#frame$frame_id[$i]').click(function() {
    $('#top-left-frame').html('<img src=\"$upper_left[$i]\" alt=\"\" />');
    $('#top-mid-frame').css('background-image','url($upper_middle[$i])'); 
    $('#top-right-frame').html('<img src=\"$upper_right[$i]\" alt=\"\" />');
    $('#mid-left-frame').css('background-image','url($middle_left[$i])'); 
    $('#mid-right-frame').css('background-image','url($middle_right[$i])'); 
    $('#bottom-left-frame').html('<img src=\"$bottom_left[$i]\" alt=\"\" />');
    $('#bottom-mid-frame').css('background-image','url($bottom_middle[$i])'); 
    $('#bottom-right-frame').html('<img src=\"$bottom_right[$i]\" alt=\"\" />');
    $('#frame-select').html('$prod_id');
    $('#pid-form').val('$frame_id[$i]');
    $('#oa_id-form').val('$prod_id');
    var frameState = $(this).attr('id');
    $.cookie('frameState', frameState, { expires: 7 });     
    alert($.cookie('frameState') + ' was clicked.');
 });
";
 }
```

Comment: That's not so clear. There do you want to record it? For each frame you are using the separate onclick handler, so you definitely able to get $i value, but I'm not sure what do you mean by recording it?

Comment: This is a picture framing application.  It allows you to choose different matting options - when you do choose a different matting option - it loads the default frame again.  I would like to save the last frame so it stops reverting back to default.  I figure if I store the value $I in a cookie it will be easy to load again.  I am new to PHP so if there is another way Id appreciate it.

Comment: also if there is something obvious that I am missing don't be shy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if "frame$frame_id[$i]" is the clicked object's id, you could possibly extract the id with:

```
$(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\[]*\[([^\]]*)\]$/, '$1')
```

this would manipulate the id and return only the value between the brackets.

Comment: didn't work exactly as planned but led me down the path to the right answer.  I just did a replace on the 'frame' with '' and got the number.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply hard-code it as you've done everywhere else in your script already?

NOTE: This is a very bad design IMHO; instead of creating all of this for EACH element in your array, you should create a static JS function that does all of this, and then call it with parameters to pass along the extra information.